# Как выбрать данные из таблицы со связями в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

В документации написано, что связи вытягиваются автоматически методом `findOne`

Вот модель:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%books}}".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $author_id
 * @property string $name
 * @property integer $date_create
 * @property integer $date_update
 * @property string $preview
 * @property integer $date
 *
 * @property Authors $author
 */
class Book extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => [  
                       'date_create',  
                       'date_update'
                    ],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['date_update'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%books}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['author_id', 'date_create', 'date_update', 'date'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name', 'preview'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'author_id' => 'Author ID',
            'authorName' => 'Author',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'date_create' => 'Date Create',
            'date_update' => 'Date Update',
            'preview' => 'Preview',
            'date' => 'Date',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
    }

    public function getAuthorName()
    {
        return $this->author['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->author['last_name'];
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить данные со связью так:

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
    return json_encode($this->findModel($id)->toArray());
}
```

чтоб использовать как ответ на ajax. Но в json объекте связанных данных не нахожу.

Что я делаю не так? Как надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код `Book::findOne($id)` вернет вам только данные объекта и не загрузит информацию из связанных таблиц.

В простом случае вам нужно использовать следующий код:

```
$book = Book::find()->with('author')->where(['id' => $id])->one();
$authorName = $book->author->name; //Получаем доступ к связанной таблице
```

Так как ваша задача запихнуть данные в `json` вам надо сформировать массив самостоятельно:

```
return json_encode(([
    'book' => $book->toArray(),
    'author' => $book->author->toArray(),
]);
```

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Код ```Book::findOne($id)``` возвращает мне объект, который содержит данные из связанной таблицы. Проблема в том, что при использовании метода ```toArray()``` эти данные теряются. Решения пока не нашел.

Comment: @Razzwan Да, данные будут доступны, но там полетит ещё один запрос в бд в момент обращения к релейшену. Попробуйте мой вариант, он рабочий. Получение объекта можно выполнить и через `findOne`.

Comment: Как ни сранно, но без **->with('author')** тоже сработает **$book->author->name**

Comment: @Adobe верно, просто с `with` данные будут выбраны из базы данных сразу, одним запросом. В случае когда идет обращение к релейшену, данные которого ещё не загружены, будет лететь дополнительный запрос. Лично я обычно использую вариант без `with`, ничего страшного что идет дополнительный запрос. Меньше кода и данные подгружаются только тогда когда они нужны. Вариант с `with` я использую для дополнительного условия в запросе или когда надо узкое место оптимизировать.

Comment: Обычно на оптимизацию начинаешь заморачиваться там, где это требуется, конкретно. Как правило никто самодеятельность оплачивать не будет :) А порой и наказуемо.

Comment: @Adobe В данном случае это скорее вопрос личного стиля программиста, так как накладных расходов нет. Я оптимизирую только узкие места, кто-то пишет с постоянным вниманием к вопросам производительности (достаточно логично сразу достать данные, если они на следующей строчке будут использоваться).

Comment: Тут выбор между наличием лишней фразы кода или наличием дополнительного запроса. Кому что нравится :)